# Google Map's marker not being displayed properly

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

The app I'm working on has a map which contains a circle on top that resembles the area that will be searched plus it shows the area in miles on top. In order to calculate the area covered, I need to find the radius of the circle after the map camera has changed (or in Apple maps terms, when the region changes). In order to test that the map is getting the right destination/length of the radius , i'm placing a marker at it's center and a marker at the boundaries of the circle. After that i calculate the radius and continue to calculate the area. I was working with Apple maps first and everything worked fine and now i switched to Google maps in order to use Places API and other API's. In Apple maps the deltaLongtiude and deltaLatitude from the region made it easy to calculate the changes when the region has been changed. In Google maps, they use Camera instead of Region. it has no deltaLatitude/Longitude (correct me if i'm wrong). I'm using the same equation here to calculate the distance using cross multiplication. When i zoom out of the map and drag the map, the center mark is placed correctly however the marker on the boundary is misplaced. Please find the code below of what I'm doing.

In viewDidLoad: i set up the map as follow:

```
GMSMarker *currentLocation = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)];
currentLocation.map = _map;

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude+0.0075 longitude:longitude zoom:13];
_map.camera = camera;

[_map setMinZoom:1 maxZoom:13];
```

The 0.0075 is just to adjust the camera properly.

Now in order to view if the markers are placed correctly, i use the following delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position{
GMSMarker *currentLocation = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(position.target.latitude-0.0075, position.target.longitude)];
currentLocation.map = _map;

GMSMarker *currentLocation2 = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(position.target.latitude-0.0075, position.target.longitude + ((0.0172*position.zoom)/13))];
currentLocation2.map = _map;
```

}

currentLocation places a marker in the center and currentLocation2 places a marker at the boundary. In order to place the marker correctly in case the user zoomed out, I do a cross multiplication. Since at zoom level 13 the boundary marker should be longitude+0.0172 from the center marker, i multiple 0.0172 by the new zoom level and divide it by 13 and add the value to he longitude. When i run the app and zoom out and drag the map, the boundary marker is misplaced. It's somehow has the same coordinates of the previous zoom level. DO i have to update anything in order to make it work or am i doing anything wrong?

to view more what i'm talking about here are pictures. The first show the map at zoom level 13. As you can see a marker in center and a boundary marker. In the second picture it's at a different zoom level and as you can see the boundary marker stays in same place and doesn't add a new one on the updated camera.

[image]

[image]